# Exact Differential Equation. Solve: $ x^4 \frac{dy}{dx} + x^3y + \operatorname{cosec} (xy) = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve:

$$ x^4 \frac{dy}{dx} + x^3y + \operatorname{cosec}(xy) = 0 $$

I want to solve the above differential equation by reducing it to Exact Differential Equation. I have verified that

$$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \ne  \frac{\partial N}{\partial y} $$

But I am not able to gather which of the five common methods to reduce a DE to Exact DE should I use?

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the embarrassing argument $xy$ of the cosecant be setting $z:=xy$, so that $y'=\dfrac{z'}x-\dfrac z{x^2}$.
This gives
$$x^3z'-x^2z+ x^2z + \operatorname{cosec} (z) = 0 ,$$ which happens to be separable:

$$\sin(z)\,z'+\frac1{x^3}=0$$ and

$$\cos(z)=\cos(xy)=C-\frac1{2x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^4 \frac{dy}{dx} + x^3y + \operatorname{cosec}(xy) = 0$$
Divide by $x^3$ and $x \ne 0$:
$$x y' + y + \frac {csc(xy)}{x^3}= 0$$
$$(xy)'+ \frac {csc(xy)}{x^3}= 0$$
$$(xy)'=- \frac {csc(xy)}{x^3}$$
It's separable:
$$\sin(xy)d(xy)=- \frac {dx}{x^3}$$
Integrate